# Python3でtesseractを用いたOCR時のエラー

Tags: python, tesseract

英語PDFのOCRをPythonで行おうと考えており、tesseract (ターミナル上では動きます) と textract ([こちら](http://www.tysonmaly.com/installing-textract-for-python-3/)の手順に沿って) のインストールは正常に行えました。

しかし、以下のコードを実行した場合にエラーが出て文字を抽出できません。

```
text = textract.process(
    '/Users/Text/en.pdf',
    method='tesseract',
    language='eng',
)
```

エラー:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/textract-1.4.0-py3.4.egg/textract/parsers/pdf_parser.py in extract_tesseract(self, filename, **kwargs)
     62                 page_content = TesseractParser().extract(page_path, **kwargs)
     63                 contents.append(page_content)
---> 64             return ''.join(contents)
     65         finally:
     66             shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

`pdf_parser.py`の修正を試みましたが、どれも失敗しました。

1. `return b''.join(contents)`と書き換える
2. Insert `contents = [str(item) for item in contents]` を `return`の前に
3. Insert `contents = [item.decode("utf-8") for item in contents]` を `return`の前に

＊こちらの質問は、[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340049/using-tesseract-in-python3-textract-library)のポストを訳したものです。どちらかで回答が得られた場合は、質問者が責任をもってもう片方に掲載します。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 確認ですが、Python2では無くPython3で動かす必要がある、という事でよろしいですか？

Comment: @mjy おっしゃる通りです。

Comment: 対処法の 3 ですが、これは `''.join([item.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(item, bytes) else item for item in contents])` とした方がよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`という同じエラーが出ます。

Comment: 1. や 3. 、あるいは metropolis さんのコメントの方法でエラーが変わらないのは変ですね(2. は変な事になると思います)。編集しているファイルを間違えていたり、エラーが変わった事に気付いていなかったりしませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `str`の`join`メソッド一般の話

`str`の`join`メソッドに渡したシーケンスに、`bytes`が含まれていると質問のエラーが出ます。

```
>>> "".join([b"abc", b"def"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-b6a19bdaade9>", line 1, in <module>
    "".join([b"abc", b"def"])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

質問中にある 3. の方法で、`bytes`を`str`にしてしまえば、このエラーは消えます。
(1. の方法でもよいですが以下は 3. を使います)

```
>>> "".join(item.decode("utf-8") for item in [b"abc", b"def"])
'abcdef'
```

ただし、シーケンスに`str`が含まれていると、今度はそちらがエラーを生みます。

```
>>> "".join(item.decode("utf-8") for item in [b"abc", b"def", "あいう"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-16-db83cb004c11>", line 1, in <module>
    "".join(item.decode("utf-8") for item in [b"abc", b"def", "あいう"])
  File "<ipython-input-16-db83cb004c11>", line 1, in <genexpr>
    "".join(item.decode("utf-8") for item in [b"abc", b"def", "あいう"])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

metropolisさんのコメントの方法で、`bytes`のみ`decode`するようにすれば、このエラーも消えます。

```
>>> "".join(item.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(item, bytes) else item for item in [b"abc", b"def", "あいう"])
'abcdefあいう'
```

#### textractの話

textractを正しくPython3に移植するには、手間も必要と思いますが、とりあえず質問のエラーを消すには、上記の方法で`decode`してしまえばよいでしょう。

pdf_parser.py 64行目`return ''.join(contents)`を

```
return "".join(item.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(item, bytes) else item
                    for item in contents)
```

とします。これでエラーは別の箇所の

> NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

になります。`unicode`はPython3にはないので、とりあえず`str`にでもして置くとして、
utils.py 54行目`if isinstance(text, unicode):`...を

```
if isinstance(text, str):
    return text
```

とします。
適当ではありますが、これで英語のみのPDFは処理出来ました。

Comment: ありがとうございました。質問に記していた通り、こちらの回答を[英語版stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340049/using-tesseract-in-python3-textract-library/38413167#38413167)にも掲載いたしました。もし何か問題がありましたらお知らせください。